# "we" and "all of us" together?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

I saw this sentence in a novel that I am reading:

> There was a chill in the air, and we were all of us tired.

The second part, using "we" together with "all of us" seemed unusual to me. Is this structure grammatically correct? If so, what kind of usage is it?

Comment: You are right that this structure seems unusual. However, it is encountered sometimes, usually in spoken language. You may also hear, for example, *we're none of us experts*. I'm sure there is an interesting linguistic analysis of this phenomenon out there somewhere, but I haven't seen one before.

Comment: Tennyson in "The Revenge" says _And the sick men down in the hold were most of them stark and cold_.

Comment: Well, it's just a [redundancy](https://literaryterms.net/pleonasm/#:~:text=A%20pleonasm%20is%20a%20literary,phrase%20pleonasmos%20meaning%20%E2%80%9Cexcessive.%E2%80%9D) used as a literary device for emphasis.

Answer (score 3):

> > There was a chill in the air, and we were all of us tired.

That is a funny way to put it. So in a non-native speaker it would be seen as wrong or awkward. In literature it would be presumed to have been done on possible and would be almost poetic.